# ReactJs Trying to get variable from callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have an `POST API` that returns the object that was just created and I would like to get the objects information in `reactjs`.

```
createItem(item){
    let temp;
    // POST to DB
    fetch(url(this.props.api), {
        method:"POST",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: item,
            isCompleted:false
        })
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response.json()
    }).then(function (body) {
        temp = body; // got the objects information
        console.log(temp);
    });

    console.log(temp);

    this.state.bucket_list.push({
        name: item,
        isCompleted: false
    });
    this.setState({bucket_list: this.state.bucket_list});

}
```

This is what I have but the I can extract the data outside the `then` function. After I get the information I would like to `setState` and append the newly created object to my `state: bucketlist`. But I think due to Javascript's asynchronous issues, I am unable to do this in the correct order. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before giving you the answer, you should know that directly mutating the state is considered as an antipattern. You should instead consider objects as immutable.

Instead of:

```
this.state.bucket_list.push({
  name: item,
  isCompleted: false
});
this.setState({bucket_list: this.state.bucket_list});
```

You should have done

```
this.setState({
  bucket_list: [
    ...this.state.bucket_list,
    {
      name: item,
      isCompleted: false
    },
  ]
});
```

---

Anyway, let me give you two different wayts to handle your usecase:

**1. Use async/await (Recommended)**

With the [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) you will be able to wait an instruction to finish before going to the next one.

```
    async createItem(item){
      // POST to DB
      const data = await fetch(url(this.props.api), {
        method:"POST",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name: item,
          isCompleted:false
        })
      });

      this.setState({
        bucket_list: [
          ...this.state.bucket_list,
          data,
        ],
      });
    }
```

**2. Keep using fetch with `then` and use arrow function**

It allows the function to not have their own `this`. That is why you can use the `this.setState` inside the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
    createItem(item){
      // POST to DB
      fetch(url(this.props.api), {
        method:"POST",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name: item,
          isCompleted:false
        })
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          bucket_list: [
            ...this.state.bucket_list,
            data,
          ],
        });
      });
    }
```

Note2: If your usecase is simple, you can keep using this method. Otherwise you should definitely take a look at [redux](http://redux.js.org/)

Comment: body is undefined in the first method tho

Comment: My bad, little typo: use `data` instead of `body`. I edited my answer accordingly.